# Query related to trigger fire in SQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle11g, triggers, database-trigger

Is it possible to fire a trigger when a row value in the table equals a certain value? Like if a value in the table hits zero, I want a certain DML operation to occur using a trigger, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Triggers fire based on events on DB objects. For example you can define a trigger to fire before or after insert, update or delete events on tables. What you do in the trigger implementation is entirely up to you, DB will make old record (for update and delete) and new record (for insert and update) available to you.

For your requirement, you can implement a logic that will check for the attribute's value and if it hits zero, you perform the DML operation else just return without doing anything.